# PHP acessando arquivos de outro micro na rede

Tags: php, apache

Sei que esta pergunta pode ser marcada como duplicada, mas não encontrei nenhuma resposta definitiva.

Afinal, é possível acessar arquivos de um computador na mesma rede, usando PHP, sem alterar configurações do Apache?

Fiz diversos testes listados abaixo, não obtive sucesso em nenhum deles.

```
<?php
    function getRealIpAddr() {

        if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
            $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        } else if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
            $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        } else {
            $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        }
        return $ip;

    } 

    echo getRealIpAddr();

    $teste = file_get_contents("file://".getRealIpAddr()."/dados_merilin/Pesquisa.pdf");

    var_dump($teste);

    $teste = file_get_contents("file:\\\\".getRealIpAddr()."\\dados_merilin\\Pesquisa.pdf");

    var_dump($teste);

    $url = file_exists("//".getRealIpAddr()."/dados_merilin/Pesquisa.pdf");
    var_dump($url);

    $url = file_exists("\\\\".getRealIpAddr()."\\dados_merilin\\Pesquisa.pdf");
    var_dump($url);

    $isFolder = is_dir("\\\\".getRealIpAddr()."\\dados_merilin");
    var_dump($isFolder);

    $isFolder = is_dir("//".getRealIpAddr()."/dados_merilin");
    var_dump($isFolder);

    $arquivo = fopen("\\\\".getRealIpAddr()."\\dados_merilin\\Pesquisa.txt", 'r');

    var_dump($arquivo);

    $arquivo = fopen("//".getRealIpAddr()."/dados_merilin/Pesquisa.txt", 'r');

    var_dump($arquivo);

?>
```

Sendo que a pasta dados_merilin esta compartilhada, com acesso full e existe o arquivo nessa pasta.

O retorno é...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então, é possível?

Comment: Rafa, acesse https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153824/php-access-network-path-under-windows isso vai te ajudar.

Comment: Alterar registros no servidor também não seria uma alternativa para mim, além de ser Linux